# Failed to Start After Moving /var to Another Drive

Tags: centos, rsync, var

I am running CentOS 7.

I have `/var` on a separate hard drive, and `smartctl` shows that it has some read error.  Hence, I would like to move `/var` to another hard drive.

For the new hard drive, I used gparted to create two partitions (1MB alignment).

Then, I mounted one partition to `/mnt/var_new` and then `rsync -avHPSAX --filter='-x security.selinux' /var/ /mnt/var_new/`.  And as expected, one file was failed to sync (that just confirmed why `smartctl` got read errors):

```
WARNING: cache/yum/x86_64/7/centos-sclo-sclo/gen/primary_db.sqlite failed verification -- update discarded (will try again).
cache/yum/x86_64/7/centos-sclo-sclo/gen/primary_db.sqlite
      1,607,680 100%    2.81MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#3, ir-chk=1309/1607)
rsync: read errors mapping "/var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/centos-sclo-sclo/gen/primary_db.sqlite": Input/output error (5)
ERROR: cache/yum/x86_64/7/centos-sclo-sclo/gen/primary_db.sqlite failed verification -- update discarded.
```

And no other file was failed to sync (I re-ran `rsync` again to confirm).

Then, I correctly removed the entry that mounted the old `/var` and added a new entry to mount the new `/var`.

Then, I rebooted and then it failed to start with tons of failures (just plain black screen).

Then, I booted into emergency mode, and the new `/var` did mount correctly that I could see the related files there.

I did read some articles that `/var` needed to be in 755 mode and `/var/tmp` needed to have the sticky bit set.  I had both.

What did I do wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: In recovery mode, `chroot` into your system, mount /var if it's not mounted, and run `restorecon -rv /var` and then try booting normally again. Make sure your `/var` entry in `/etc/fstab` is correct.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov you mean running the command with the new `/var`?

Comment: Yes, with the new /var.

Comment: I can't help with your booting probs, but if it comes up `yum clean all` should be able to work around that one file being corrupted.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov it works!  could you make it an answer?  I will accept it.  Thanks!

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco yeah, likely `yum clean all` could get rid of the file but for some reason, when I `yum` again, the file got created at the same spot (the corrupted sector).  Anyway, thanks for your tips!

Comment: @HCSF I had meant once you got the machine fixed that the corrupted file isn't that important and can be recreated.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco ah, got it!  thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In recovery mode:

1. `chroot` into your system
2. `mount /var` if it's not mounted
3. `restorecon -rv /var` and then try booting normally again.

Make sure your `/var` entry in `/etc/fstab` is correct.